# file_get_contents

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Como pegar o valor da cotação através do file get contents da seguinte pagina: https://www.google.com/finance?q=USDBRL&ei=tb1KWOHWLMX_mAGJyLnIBw

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Podes usar esta api, http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD , a base é o usd, depois um dos valores é brl

Comment: Sua pergunta ficou um bocado ampla. Poste o que tentou, e a dificuldade exata que está tendo, para que seja possível a ajuda. Já adianto que querer extrair dados diretamente de página nesses casos costuma ser algo extremamente precário, provavelmente você investiria melhor o tempo procurando alguma API que forneça os dados que busca. Páginas são feitas para humanos obterem informação, APIs são feitas para máquinas e sistemas obterem informação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz um código aqui e consegui pegar o resultado:

```
$html = file_get_contents( "https://www.google.com/finance?q=USDBRL&ei=tb1KWOHWLMX_mAGJyLnIBw" );
$content = new DOMDocument();
@$content->loadHTML( $html );
$itens = $content->getElementsByTagName( "span" );

$cotacao = null;

foreach( $itens as $item ) {

    if ( stripos( $item->getAttribute( "class"), "pr" ) !== false )
        $cotacao = str_replace( "1 USD = ", "", $item->nodeValue );
}

echo trim( $cotacao );
```

Comment: Está extremamente precário, mais funciona bem.

Comment: hahaha, achei muita cara de pau o cara postar só foto e pedir código pronto, mas tu tirou onda pegando os spans e procurando o que tem essa classe pr :)

Comment: é, o complicado dessa "solução" é que mudando o nome das classes, ou o elemento, já para de funcionar. Por isso o ideal é usar uma API.

Comment: Concordo em gênero, número e grau. Isso aí é daquelas soluções q a gente faz pra quebrar o galho de vez em quando, mas sabe que vai ter que alterar em algum momento.